# Kendo RangeSlider breaks in chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, nopcommerce

I have implemented kendo range slider for eCommerce store. It works fine when changes made in firefox. But it goes disappeared or breaks in chrome after slide.

Kendo version is 2014.1.318 and uses jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2.

Please help to overcome this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you tried on kendo dojo ? i tried kendo version 2014.1.318 [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/aTuRE) on chrome(idk what your chrome version is) it works, best way to know it is try do the same thing on kendo dojo or js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of Chrome doesn't support **".contains()"** method of jQuery. Instead of using **.indexOf()** method, it works perfectly in Chrome & Safari browser.

Refer this links:

1. [Error using .contains() JQuery function in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326813/error-using-contains-jquery-function-in-chrome)
2. [jquery "contains" code doesn't work on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387915/jquery-contains-code-doesnt-work-on-chrome)